# How to filter Sanity posts by category title?

Tags: sanity, groq

Here what I've done in vision

```
*[_type == "post" && categories == SOCIAL ]{
  _id, title
}
```

It returned

```
No documents found in dataset production that match query:


*[_type == "post" && categories == SOCIAL ]{
  _id, title
}
```

Comment: Is `categories` an array that can contain the string `"SOCIAL"`? If so you have to use `in`: `*[_type == "post" && "SOCIAL" in categories]`.

Comment: @AlexanderStaubo 
No documents found in dataset production that match query:

*[_type == "post" && "SOCIAL" in categories]

Comment: Is `categories` an array of strings?

Comment: @AlexanderStaubo

"result":[8 items
0:{6 items
"_createdAt":"2021-12-15T05:14:53Z"
"_id":"167d5d3e-ce1b-4f0c-a092-aa81213bed41"
"_rev":"wY9KfPeCwmcMrJtIpsqdOq"
"_type":"category"
"_updatedAt":"2021-12-15T05:14:53Z"
"title":"SOCIAL"
}

Comment: So it's not an array of strings. You need to write it like this: `"SOCIAL" in categories[].title`. If `categories` is an array of refs, however, you need to write it like this: `"SOCIAL" in categories[]->title`.

Comment: @AlexanderStaubo "No documents found in dataset production that match query: " for both

Comment: Flagging this question because the author should provide one of: content schema or at least the result of querying `post` documents without other filters. Otherwise, people have to guess the structure of documents so they can't provide a correct answer

Answer (score 4):

```
*[_type == "post" &&  "social" in categories[]->title]{
title
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to format it like so:

```
*[_type == "post" && categories == "SOCIAL" in categories[]->title]{
  title,
  slug,
  body
}
```

If nothing shows up then there are no posts associated with that category. Categories are also case sensitive, so make sure your capitalization is right.

Answer (score 0):

*[_type == 'post' && category->name == 'Technology']

Can also try this in cases where your categories are not saved as arrays.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is instead of searching by the name of the category i searched using the `._ref` property of the category.
It would look something like this

```
    *[_type == "post" && categories == categories._ref]
```